# How can we built History map in HEVC?

Tags: video, encoding, hevc, h.265

How can we keep historical information of previous frame Information which can be used in future frames Encoding?

Comment: Are you asking how to perform [interframe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter_frame) compression? HEVC is almost always inter-coded.

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific? What kind of data? "Long Term Reference"? Only the decoder and the format of the bitstream are standardised, which means that for the encoder you can do whatever you feel like as long as the corresponding bitstream adheres to the standard!

Comment: Yes i want to perform Inter frame Compression @Mulvya

Comment: i want to save information (Motion, RD cost etc.) for previous frames which will be used in future frame for Encoding basically want to reduce Complexity for encoder @FredrikPihl

Comment: That's what HEVC (and like) compression schemes already do. You can either do it dynamically during encoding (1-pass bitrate or CRF mode) or as a separate step (1st pass of 2-pass bitrate).

Comment: I have to agree with @Mulvya so far. Keeping a history might be interesting if you are doing a special kind of rate-controller though that falls out of the scope of the normal CBR/VBR approach...